# 2 divs in one row in Safari [error]

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm a having a little problem trying to put 2 divs in one line in Safari. It's just an HTML for a test (http://www.despegarboido.byethost22.com/) The problem is that when I open it on Safari, all of my rows collapse into the same column.
My html looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftColumn"></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"></div>
</div>

.row {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
}
.leftColumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff33;
    width: 60%;
    height: 330px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.rightColumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #8cb6dd;
    background: url(images/playa1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40%;
    height: 330px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Those divs should be one next to the other, It works on every other browser, and I cant find a way to make it work on Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reduce the width of your `divs`. The width of `leftColumn` is 60% and the width of the `rightColumn` is 40%. Your logic is correct, but you have not taken the margins into account. For example, you applied the following `margin: 5px 5px 5px 20px` to the div with the class name `leftColumn`. So, the total space `leftColumn` is occupying will be equal to `60% of the page + 25px`. I am adding `25px` to the total space because the right margin is equal to `5px` and the left margin is equal to `20px`.

Because you have not accounted for the margins when assigning the width to `leftColumn` and `rightColumn` your `rightColumn` is being pushed to the next line due to less space on the previous line.

Comment: You are right! Thank you! Do you have any idea how could I fix this? Because if i reduce the width it wont look okay in the other browsers. The same with the margin.

Comment: @TomásBoido You are facing this issue because every browser has its own stylesheet. For example, in Chrome, the default `margin` may be set to `3px` whereas in safari the `margin` may only be `2px`. The easiest way to solve this issue is by resetting the browser's stylesheet. To do this, add the following code to your CSS: `body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px}`. After you do this, you will need to make some tweaks to the existing `margin` values in your code to produce the effect you want, but when you are done all the browsers will render your web page as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make them inline from the CSS as below,

Create a class say myDiv and within your CSS add below line,

```
.myDiv{
    display: inline;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="leftColumn myDiv"></div>
    <div class="rightColumn myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

[**Here is an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/jbybph7r/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didnt help, It looks still the same.

Comment: @TomásBoido did you checked the link to the fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code (recently updated):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="left">
        <div class="inner" id="leftinner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="right">
        <div class="inner" id="rightinner"></div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
}
.column {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    float: left;
}
.inner {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    height: 330px;
}
#leftinner {
    background-color: #ffff33;
}
#left {
    width: 60%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#rightinner {
    background-color: #8cb6dd;
    background: url(images/playa1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#right {
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

This version avoids repeating style definitions unnecessarily and also fixes the width problem.  See it in action: http://cssdeck.com/labs/khpx1e8y

Comment: I just updated the code to obtain the desired results.  Try it now to see if it works for you.  http://cssdeck.com/labs/khpx1e8y